# Uploading ZIP file to S3, use EC2 to Unzip

Tags: php, codeigniter, amazon-s3, amazon-ec2

I have a Codeigniter web app that is uploading many tiny files every hour to Amazon S3, which is causing my S3 request charges to shoot up real fast. One way to overcome this will be to zip up the file, upload the zip file to S3, then unzip it when it is on S3.

Can this be done using EC2? Or is there a better method to achieve this? Thank you!!

EDIT: If I were to use EC2, do I use PHP to trigger the creation of a EC2 instance, upload the PHP file required to unzip the zipped files, copy the uncompressed files to S3, then destroy the EC2 instance?

Comment: Can't you store zipped files on S3?

Comment: I want the individual unzipped files to be available on S3. Reason for zipping it (100 small files into 1 zip file) is to reduce the number of `PUT` requests which is increasing the costs of S3 usage significantly.

Comment: Uploading ZIP files to S3 and unzipping them on EC2 to lower your costs won't help: it'd still cost you a PUT request for every single unzipped file coming to S3 from EC2.

Comment: @Daan I checked that out at https://forums.aws.amazon.com/message.jspa?messageID=243519 and it appears that the COPY request from EC2 to S3 is free. Can anyone confirm this?

Comment: I think what they're discussing there is data transfer fees. You're charged separately for the actual number of requests you make, and I don't think that these requests are free even if they are coming from EC2 :) Can someone confirm?

Answer (score 32, accepted):

If you have an EC2 machine in the same region I would suggest you upload it there zipped and then it drop it to s3 from there unzipped. S3 cannot unzip it on its own as its all static.

Theres no charges between ec2 and s3 so ec2 can handle the unzipping and then write it out into your s3 bucket without additional transfer charges.

Comment: The bandwidth is free, but you will pay for PUTs (currently $0.005 per 1,000 requests). If you have a zip file with 10,000's of small files, the upload will cost something, and more importantly, it will take a while.

Comment: Dear @Akshat, please share link or code to write a folder (which has just unzipped ) into S3 from EC2 if you have that, It would be greatly appreciated

Comment: No need to use ec2 for something so simple. Use Lambda. The project that Aman Garg linked to could easily be modified to pull the file from S3 rather than receive it as an upload. https://github.com/mehmetboraezer/aws-lambda-unzip

Comment: @BrunoBronosky lambda functions run up to 15 minutes per execution. If zip is big, it will fail. Also lambda has limited space (atm 512Mb at /tmp), unless disc is attached with extra space. So this is another hard limit w/o extra config.

Answer (score 11):

You can write code in a lambda to unzip a file of S3 bucket, you just have to use it, AWS Lambda will do this for you.

Referece:

1. https://github.com/carloscarcamo/aws-lambda-unzip-py/blob/master/unzip.py
2. https://github.com/mehmetboraezer/aws-lambda-unzip

Comment: I like both of your references, but I don't know how to reconcile the fact that links to external resources are not considered valid SO answers. While you could include the content of the py files (even though you didn't link directly to it on the 2nd reference, both are a single py file) that doesn't "feel" entirely right to do. But if it's properly cited, I guess it's just archiving the script for posterity.

Answer (score 4):

S3 is just storage. Whatever file you upload is the file that is stored. You cannot upload a zip file then extract it once its in S3. If you wrote the application the best thing I could say is to try to re-design how you store the files. S3 requests are pretty cheap... you must be making a lot of requests.

Comment: You could have a trigger on upload that would start a lambda function job of unziping it to a specified bucket.

Answer (score 1):

I have been using this service to unzip files full of thousands of tiny image files, each zip I upload is about 4GB, and costs around $1 to unzip using http://www.cloudzipinc.com/service/s3_unzip, maybe that might help someone.

Having said that, you might find it easier to use Python with the Boto library. That will work far more efficiently than PHP.