# Unzip file on ec2 and save it on S3?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-s3

I have a zip file that is about 20 GB large and contains about 400'000 images that I was able to move to my EC2 instance by using `wget`. Now I want to unzip the files and save them to my S3.

Preferably it would be great if I didnt need to unzip them to the ec2 first. Can I by SSH somehow use `unzip -options` to extract each file to S3?

I have found answers like this https://stackoverflow.com/a/9722141/2335675. But I have no understanding of what he actually means by "unzipping it to S3". Can I do this while connected to my EC2 instance by SSH? Do Amazon have some kind of build in unzip command that extracts it to the s3 instead of the current server?

I can see other people have asked this questions, but I'm unable to find a direct answer of how to actually do it.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/9722141/2335675 has answered your question. S3 is just storage. S3 cannot unzip it on its own as its all static.So you have to unzip on ec2

Comment: Did you even read my post? I'm linking to that answer in my post and I'm pointing out it does not describe how to actually use ec2 to unzip it and use S3 as the destination by using the unzip ssh command.

It's just saying "unzip it by using ec2" which is not an answer to my question of how to actually do that.

Comment: unzip is the command, if you don't know how to use it, `man unzip` gives your the instruction. such as `scp your.zip.file user@ec2.server:.; ssh user@ec2.server "unzip your.zip.file"`, is this the answer you ask for?

Comment: People are saying "Unzip it and write it to S3". My question is if I can unzip it and set the destination of the unzip to S3. Please read.

Comment: S3 is storage, it should be mount by ec2, so you see S3 as one of filesystem in ec2.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

How I solved it:

1. I created a secondary volume on my EC2 instance to have space for the file x3 or so, to also include space for the extracted files. See guide here: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/ec2-add-volume-to-instance.html
2. By being connected to the EC2 instance by SSH, I used the `unzip`command to unzip the file to the new volume.
3. I used `aws s3 cp myfolder s3://mybucket/myfolder --recursive` to move all my files into my S3 bucket.
4. I deleted my temporary volume and all files on it.

Everything was done using SSH. No script or programming was required.

Remember you need to use `sudo` to have permission to do many of the things.

Comment: How much does it cost to move 400,000 files from EC2 to S3?

Answer (score 1):

- The first solution:

  1. Mount s3 on ec2 using [s3fs](https://code.google.com/p/s3fs/wiki/FuseOverAmazon).
  2. Extract files to the mount point.
- The second solution:

  1. Using python and its aws library [boto](https://github.com/boto/boto)
  2. extracting one file to the temporal location using `zipfile`
  3. and uploading it to s3 using `boto`,
  4. then delete the temporal file.
  5. go to 2 while finishied

Comment: For what it's worth, you can actually do all of the file IO in memory by using boto and python's zipfile module: `for subfile in zipf.namelist():
            k = Key(bucket)
            k.key = PUBLIC_PREFIX+subfile
            k.set_contents_from_string(zipf.read(subfile))`