# How to unzip 10gb file on AWS S3 browser

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-cli

suggest the best process using aws cli or any alternatives by downloading to local using s3 browser and upload. (After extracting locally it is 60gb file).

Comment: Please clarify your problem.  The title says "How to unzip ...".  Is that the question, or is the question "How to download ..."?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Uploading ZIP file to S3, use EC2 to Unzip](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9719302/uploading-zip-file-to-s3-use-ec2-to-unzip)

Answer (score 2):

Amazon S3 is purely a **storage service**. There is no in-built capability to process data (eg to unzip a file).

You would need to download the file, unzip it, and upload the result back to S3. This would best be done via an **Amazon EC2 instance** in the same region. (AWS Lambda only has 500MB temporary storage space, so this is not an option for a 60GB file.)

Answer (score -1):

You could look at a combination of mime-type and content-disposition meta info on the stored files as .gz

Then even let a web browser deal with decompressing etc., once received compressed.

But, I'm not totally sure what you are after.